# php, explode is not working, php preg_replace is not working

Tags: php, preg-replace, explode

AbraCadaver gave me a link to phpsandbox. The code below works on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/  .

Why it does not work in my computer? I have wampstack-5.6.20-0, php version 5.6.20 and check oce on Opera, Firefox, Explorer and Chrome.

I have a string, which i would like to split to pieces in order to join them with a glue string OR preg_replace the split_substring(aaaa) with a glue_string (jsonString) :

```
$tmpStr = '<br><div id="10"><p>Displaying 1-5 of 11 results. <br> <span class="disabled">&laquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&lsaquo;</span> Page 1 of 3 pages<a href="?page=2&amp;formData=aaaa" title="Next page">&rsaquo;</a> <a href="?page=3&amp;formData=aaaa" title="Last page">&raquo;</a><br>All pages: <a href="?page=1&amp;formData=aaaa">1</a> <a href="?page=2&amp;formData=aaaa">2</a> <a href="?page=3&amp;formData=aaaa">3</a>  </p></div><br> ';

$tmpArr = explode("aaaa", $tmpStr);
print_r("<br> 94 EventSearchCOntroller tmpArr =<pre>"); print_r($tmpArr);
```

**Result is:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
 107 PaginatorTrait pagHTML = 
Displaying 1-5 of 11 results. 
 « ‹ Page 1 of 3 pages› »
All pages: 1 2 3  
)

$tmpStr2=preg_replace( "/aaaa/", "jsonString", $tmpStr ); 
$tmpStr2=preg_replace( "/aaaa/", "jsonString", $tmpStr, 100 ); 
print_r( "<br> 97 EventSearchCOntroller tmpStr2 =".$tmpStr2 );

//Result is in both cases (using 100 limit, and without a limit):
 97 EventSearchCOntroller tmpStr2 =
```

If I print the results, the string is not splitted. Where is the reason?

Comment: What do you mean? `$tmpStr2` is a string and not an array.

Comment: No - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/82291d872333aa00ae9d885a5b16617f87637832

Comment: When you see the output on a browser, the browser interprets the <a.. tags and shows a link instead of the strings you are expecting. That is why you get 1 2 3 as a link, instead of the string exploded. The string is clearly split but browser is interpreting the strings.

Comment: Just view the source to see that it is split. Use browser's view source.

Comment: IN case of explode, string is not exploded. The results is the array with a single item. If it would be explodd, i would get 4 items in the array.

Comment: TmpStr2 should contain the result of preg_replace. I am getting the empty string instead og a string where "aaaa" are replaced with "jsonString".

Comment: Thank you for the sandbox. It works on sandbox, but not on my computer.

Comment: In case of preg_replace, the reason is that i should use`i`  in replacement expression `'/aaaa/i'` . Maybe in some cases it is also good to use preg_quate.

Comment: i mean preg_quote

Comment: @olga I beg to differ. The string is clearly exploded. Instead of using var_dump, try to iterate over the array and display its contents. You will see that the exploding is done.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this and see the output:

```
$tmpStr = '<br><div id="10"><p>Displaying 1-5 of 11 results. <br> <span class="disabled">&laquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&lsaquo;</span> Page 1 of 3 pages<a href="?page=2&amp;formData=aaaa" title="Next page">&rsaquo;</a> <a href="?page=3&amp;formData=aaaa" title="Last page">&raquo;</a><br>All pages: <a href="?page=1&amp;formData=aaaa">1</a> <a href="?page=2&amp;formData=aaaa">2</a> <a href="?page=3&amp;formData=aaaa">3</a>  </p></div><br> ';

$tmpArr = explode("aaaa", $tmpStr);
echo "<textarea rows='20' cols='120'>";
print_r($tmpArr);
echo "</textarea>";
```